# Time trigger in telegraf js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am making a Telegram bot with Telegraf framework in JavaScript with nodeJS. I want to send a message to the user every Monday morning at 9.00 AM. How can I make this time based trigger in telegraf js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telegraf doesn't provide you with such abilities out-of-the-box since it's a bot framework with the goal of abstracting API calls. You should instead schedule the task with task scheduling libraries (like node-cron).

An example with [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 9 * * MON', () => {
  // send the message here
  bot.telegram.sendMessage(12345678, "scheduled message");
});

bot.launch()
```

If you want to learn a bit more about it, please [refer this tutorial](https://alligator.io/nodejs/node-cron/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any other libraries, try using `Date` object.

```
let goalTime = new Date(December 17, 2020 13:24:00)
```

And use `if` to check `Date.now()` :

```
let currentTime = Date.now()
if (currentTime == goalTime) {
    ctx.reply("your message")
}
```

For sending message weekly (below code is just an example, you can also use hour and minute to specify time):

```
const goalTime = new Date(December 17, 2020 13:24:00)
const weekday = goalTime.getDay()
let currentTime = Date.now
let currentDay = currentTime.getDay()
if (currentDay == weekday) {
ctx.reply("your message")
}
```

You can refer to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more details on `Date`.